# call javascript after updatepanel postback

Tags: asp.net

I put the following javascript code inline but it doesn't trigger after the updatepanel is done with its postback:

```
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) { alert("this should work"); }
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET - UpdatePanel and JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418072/asp-net-updatepanel-and-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, nevermind, I got it. If someone else runs into this problem, put the sys.webforms..... line like this:

```
$(document).ready( function () { sys.webforms....; }
```

Comment: As a touch of commentary, this requires that you be using jQuery in the first place. Alternately there's a way to do this with straight ASP.NET javascript libraries

Comment: Works well *thump up*

Answer (score 1):

Do following thing place following function on dom load.

```
function load() {
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be help you.

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
if (prm != null) {
    prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
        if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
            DisplayCurrentTime(); // here your javascript function
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear up the confusion here is the full code

```
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) 
         { yourFunction(); }

jQuery(document).ready(function (){
         Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
      });
```

Hope this helps!