# Call JQUERY function from Client Side (VB sub)

Tags: jquery, vb.net

How can i call a jquery method from vb sub routine?

My code is when it returns false, the div which contains an alert message will show.

Her'es my code, but its not working:

```
If res = Nothing Then
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "PopupMessage", "$('.styleError').toggle('5000');", True)
End IF
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this in an UpdatePanel? If so, see [ASP.NET - UpdatePanel and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418072/asp-net-updatepanel-and-javascript) .

Also, check the Javascript console in the browser to see if any errors are generated, for example you might find that you need to wrap your code in a way similar to $(document).ready(function() {/* your code here */} )